# Cannot determine terminal size with ncurses

Tags: c++, macos, ncurses

I am trying to handle a resize signal (SIGWINCH)

```cpp
void Server::resizeSignalHandler(int a)
{
signal(SIGWINCH, SIG_IGN);

endwin();
initscr();
refresh();
clear();

int x,y;
getmaxyx(stdscr, y, x);

wmove(upScreen, 0, 0);
wmove(downScreen, y/2, 0);
wresize(upScreen, y/2, x);
wresize(downScreen, y/2, x);
wclear(upScreen);
wclear(downScreen);
waddstr(upScreen, "test1");
waddstr(downScreen, "test2");
wrefresh(upScreen);
wrefresh(downScreen);
refresh();

signal(SIGWINCH, Server::resizeSignalHandler);

}
Server::Server()
{
//ncurses screen initialization
initscr();

if (!upScreen) {
    upScreen = newwin(0, 0, 1, 1);
}
if (!downScreen) {
    downScreen = newwin(0, 0, 1, 1);
}
//adjusting screen when user resize terminal
signal(SIGWINCH, Server::resizeSignalHandler);

//configuring screens
Server::resizeSignalHandler(0);

waddstr(Server::upScreen, "lalfasdfsafd as");
waddstr(downScreen, "supreme!");
wrefresh(Server::upScreen);
wrefresh(downScreen);
}
```

When I was debugging this code, in resizeSignalHandler var x,y were always the same (size didn't change). I also tried determine size with ioctl, but nothing's changed.

I figured out that many people before me had this problem
http://www.mail-archive.com/arch@archlinux.org/msg11253.html
Sometimes, they solved that (changing /etc/profile ;O (sic!)), but sometimes not.
Is there any alternative to mac os x terminal, maybe ncurses is dedicated for xterm and similar.

Comment: You can make OSX term behaves as xterm so that's not the problem. Are you really testing in the terminal or in XCode's fake term?

Comment: It cannot be tested in xcode. In terminal.

Comment: The example shown in the question interferes with the [`SIGWINCH`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_initscr.3x.html#h3-Signal-Handlers) handler set up by ncurses, and does it unsafely.  None of the suggested answers is helpful...

Answer (score 1):

That’s because the values you get with `getmaxyx` are updated themselves by a signal handler listening to `SIGWINCH`. You need to save the pointer to the old signal with something like:

```
old_callback = signal(SIGWINCH, Server::resizeSignalHandler);
```

and then call it in `resizeSignalHandler`:

```
old_callback(a);
```

Answer (score 1):

`getmaxyx(...)` gives wrong (not updated) terminal sizes because of custom `SIGWINCH` signal handler.

You can use `ioctl(fileno(stdout), TIOCGWINSZ, struct winsize*)` to get updated terminal parameters. But this won't update data returned by `getmaxyx(...)`.

To update `getmaxyx(...)` data, you should call `resize_term(size.ws_row, size.ws_col)`

So the signal handler code should look like:

```
void on_terminal_resize(int n) {
    struct winsize size;

    if (ioctl(fileno(stdout), TIOCGWINSZ, &size) == 0) {
        resize_term(size.ws_row, size.ws_col);
    }
    // Your code goes here...
    signal(SIGWINCH, on_terminal_resize);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but I think you have to call `ioctl(1, TIOCGWINSZ, struct winsize*)` to get the updated terminal parameters.  See `man tty_ioctl`.

Answer (score -1):

I don't have a mac machine, and cant test this. But I suppose the pseudo terminal bash is running on updates $LINES and $COLUMNS but these updates are not passed to the pseudo terminal your program is assigned to. This is because you say the WINCH signal is caught, but those params are not updated. A workaround is to execute `"/usr/X11/bin/resize"` / `"/usr/bin/resize"`  in the signal handler. Probably that would properly update $LINES and $COLUMNS.

Comment: actually it works. But when I am trying to read shell variables (by echo $LINES) it returns incorrect values (like ioctl, getmaxyx etc.), thankfully /usr/X11/bin/resize directly returns correct information - so I simply husk needed information from string.